# SQL Server - Instead of Insert Trigger - override truncation error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Scenario: using an "Instead of Insert" trigger to a different table (overriding inserting into the current table) throws a truncation error.

1. Try to insert data into TableA
2. Instead Of Trigger is setup to run on TableA
3. This trigger instead inserts into TableB
4. TableA is not written to

Issue:

TableA has a `nvarchar(10) desc` column and TableB has a `nvarchar(200) desc` column. An insert trigger is setup on TableA where the data for the `desc` column is 50 characters long.

1. With `SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON (`the default), TableA causes a truncation error.
2. With `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF` (dangerous), truncation is ignored on TableB. So if the desc came in at 400 characters, it would be truncated to 200 characters with no errors.

***Setup***

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[results]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [causefailure] [nvarchar](5) NULL, 
    [type] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL, 
    [description] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [rundate] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate())
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_table]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [description] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [rundate] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate())
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[InsteadTrigger] 
ON [dbo].[test_table]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO results([type], [description])
        SELECT 
            (CASE SUBSTRING([description], 1, 1)
                WHEN 'a' 
                   THEN 'causes failure or truncation'
                   ELSE ''
             END AS [causefailure],
             'Instead Of Trigger' AS [type],
             [description]
        FROM inserted
    END;
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[test_table] ENABLE TRIGGER [InsteadTrigger]
GO
```

First attempt:

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF

INSERT INTO [dbo].[test_table]([description])
    SELECT 'atest12345678910' AS [description]
```

Second attempt:

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON

INSERT INTO [dbo].[test_table]([description])
    SELECT 'btest12345678910' AS [description]
INSERT INTO [dbo].[test_table]([description])
    SELECT 'atest12345678910' AS [description]
```

But when I run the the first code snippet, `causefailure` gets truncated. But there is no error. Running the second snippet inserts one record in [results]. But it throws an exception on the second.

Is there a way to ignore: constraints, conversion issues, etc., exceptions with the initial write to [test_table]? But have exceptions for any work done in the trigger (e.g. inserting into [results] and maybe even the actual work to [test_tables])?

> Edit: I do not want to change the column size of `nvarchar(10) desc`
>   on TableA. The ultimate goal might be if the "instead of trigger"
>   fails to insert on TableA, it saves to TableB. Or it might even change
>   the size of `desc` on failure dynamically inside the trigger and retry
>   the insert.

Hopefully helpful!

Comment: I was also interested if there was such a thing as a "instead of insert" trigger that could be written in CLR C#. But I need the above solved first.

Comment: The goal would be to change the schema of test_table if the insert fails and try the insert again. Like in a try/catch. I will include this in the question.

Comment: Use a stored procedure to deal with this, instead of having an opaque trigger that redirects your INSERT. Errors in triggers will fail the batch anyway unless you use TRY/CATCH

Comment: The *trigger* isn't doing anything about truncation. By the time the trigger fires, the truncation has *already happened*.

Comment: With a instead of trigger, truncation has not happened. Turning ansi warnings off allows a 50 character string to save to Tableb with no problems. Even though TableA has a varchar(10) for that column.

Comment: @gbn using a stored procedure would work. But EF is generating the tables. I see too much development work behind creating stored procedures for every table. Unless maybe using a CREATE_TABLE trigger to build that stored procedure?

Comment: Then get EF to design the tables correctly. It's a bad solution you ask for.

Comment: Agreed. SQL Server simply doesn't do what I need it to. Thank you gbn and damien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an incomplete idea how to work-around the above problem. It kind of evasive. But interesting way test how far you can rework a database.

The below changes the schema around when a table is created or altered. On creating or altering a table, it will be swapped out for an indexed view after the table gets renamed.

```
ALTER TRIGGER trigger_CreateTable
    ON DATABASE
    AFTER CREATE_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE
AS
BEGIN
    --SELECT EVENTDATA()

    DECLARE @Prefix AS nvarchar(256) = N'PleaseUseView_'

    DECLARE @Event AS XML = EVENTDATA()
    DECLARE @SchemaName AS nvarchar(255) = (@Event.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]',  'NVARCHAR(255)')) 
    DECLARE @TableName AS nvarchar(255) = (@Event.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]',  'NVARCHAR(255)')) 
    DECLARE @ObjectType AS nvarchar(255) = (@Event.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectType)[1]',  'NVARCHAR(255)'))
    DECLARE @TableWithSchema AS nvarchar(512) = '[' + @SchemaName + '].[' + @TableName + ']'

    CREATE TABLE #SchemaBindingDependencies
    (
        [id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
        [schema] nvarchar(256) NOT NULL,
        [name] nvarchar(256) NOT NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO #SchemaBindingDependencies([schema], [name])
        SELECT DISTINCT s.name AS [schema], o.name
        FROM sys.objects AS o
            INNER JOIN sysdepends AS d
                ON d.id = o.[object_id]
            INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
                ON s.[schema_id] = o.[schema_id]
        WHERE     o.type ='V' AND d.depid = OBJECT_ID(@TableWithSchema)
              AND SUBSTRING(@TableName, LEN(@Prefix) + 1, 256) LIKE o.[name]

    IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #SchemaBindingDependencies))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Index AS int = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM #SchemaBindingDependencies)
        WHILE (@Index > 0)
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @ViewName1 AS nvarchar(256) = (SELECT [name] FROM #SchemaBindingDependencies WHERE id = @Index)
            IF (@ViewName1 IS NOT NULL)
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @SchemaName1 AS nvarchar(256) = (SELECT [schema] FROM #SchemaBindingDependencies WHERE id = @Index)
                DECLARE @DropSchemaBoundViewQuery AS nvarchar(1000) = 'DROP VIEW [' + @SchemaName + '].[' + @ViewName1 + ']'

                EXEC(@DropSchemaBoundViewQuery)
            END

            SET @Index = @Index - 1
        END
    END

    IF (SUBSTRING(@TableName, 1, LEN(@Prefix)) <> @Prefix)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @NewTableName AS nvarchar(512) = @Prefix + @TableName + ''
        DECLARE @NewTableWithSchema AS nvarchar(512) = '[' + @SchemaName + '].[' + @NewTableName + ']'

        EXEC sp_rename @TableWithSchema, @NewTableName

        SET @TableName = @NewTableName
        SET @TableWithSchema = '[' + @SchemaName + '].[' + @NewTableName + ']'
    END

    DECLARE @Columns AS nvarchar(max) = (STUFF((SELECT ',[' + x.[name] + ']' FROM (
        SELECT c.[name]
        FROM sys.columns AS c
            INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
                ON t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
            INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
                ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
        WHERE t.[name] = @TableName AND s.[name] = @SchemaName) AS x FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''))

    DECLARE @ViewName AS nvarchar(256) = SUBSTRING(@TableName, LEN(@Prefix) + 1, 256)
    DECLARE @ViewWithSchema AS nvarchar(512) = '[' + @SchemaName + '].[' + @ViewName + ']'

    DECLARE @Query AS nvarchar(max) =
        N'CREATE VIEW ' + @ViewWithSchema + N' ' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) +
        N'WITH SCHEMABINDING ' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) +
        N'AS ' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) +
        N'  SELECT ' + @Columns + ' ' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) +
        N'  FROM ' + @TableWithSchema + N' '
    --SELECT @Query
    EXEC(@Query)

    SET @Query =
        N'CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [CIX_' + @ViewName + N'] ' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) +
        N'ON ' + @ViewWithSchema + N'(' + @Columns + N')'
    EXEC(@Query)

    -- TODO: Use the below double commented to build a variable insert statement for the "Instead of TRIGGER"
    --
    ----DECLARE @tv_source TABLE (id int)
    ----declare @XML xml;
    ----set @XML = 
    ----  (
    ----  select top(0) *
    ----  from @tv_source
    ----  for XML RAW, ELEMENTS, XMLSCHEMA  
    ----  );
    ----SELECT T.c.query('.'), T.c.value('@name', 'nvarchar(256)')
    ----FROM @XML.nodes('/*/*/*/*/*') AS T(c)
    --
    --SET @Query =
    --  N'CREATE TRIGGER [Trigger_' + @ViewName + N'] ' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) +
    --  N'ON ' + @ViewWithSchema + N' ' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) +
    --  N'INSTEAD OF INSERT ' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) +
    --  N'AS BEGIN ' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) +
    --  N'BEGIN TRY ' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) +
    --  N' INSERT INTO ' + @TableWithSchema + N'(' + @Columns + N')'
    --  N'   SELECT ' + @Columns + 
    --EXEC(@Query)
END
```

> Ideally, you would use a different schema for tables. And use dbo or
>   the default for the view.

Once the `Instead of TRIGGER` is working, you could wrap a TRY/CATCH around it. On the catch, check schema for truncation. And expand the column sizes if needed.

Incomplete solution. But it is the answer I will stick with for now.
If anyone has any better answers or a complete solution, please add it!

tl;dr

One interesting thing is the below query

```
DECLARE @tv_source TABLE (id int)
declare @XML xml;
select top(0) *
from @tv_source
for XML RAW, ELEMENTS, XMLSCHEMA
```

You can return schema. SOAP for the above XML. Or JsonSchema or Avro if using the SQL 2016+ Json version to build Restful API's with schema awareness. And with schema awareness, an application gateway could auto-grab many dispersed Micro-Rest API's into one seemly large Rest API.

Comment: Although there are different databases technologies out there that treat schema as a second class citizen (most non-relational such as MongoDB/PostgreSQL-NoSQL), I am currently stuck with SQL Server. I want SQL Server to be more. But I know it is what it is.